# Why can a read-lock be acquired when a write-lock is pending?

Tags: pthreads

According to the POSIX documentation for pthread_rwlock_rdlock "The calling thread acquires the read lock if a writer does not hold the lock and there are no writers blocked on the lock." I seem to have found that a read-lock can be acquired even when a writer is blocked. The output of a small sample I wrote looks like this:

```
first reader acquiring lock...
first reader lock acquired
first writer acquiring lock...
second reader acquiring lock...
second reader lock acquired
first reader releasing lock
second reader releasing lock
first writer lock acquired
first writer releasing lock
```

Any suggestions as to what is wrong with my code, or to what I don't correctly understand?
By the way:

```
$ make
gcc -g -I. -I../../isilib -c -Wpointer-arith -Wall -pedantic-errors
-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -std=c99 -g rwlock_test1.c -o rwlock_test1.o
gcc rwlock_test1.o -L../../isilib -lisi -lrt -lm -pthread -o rwlock_test1
$ uname -a
Linux BLACKHEART 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 
2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PTH_create( a, b, c, d ) \
    (pthread_create( (a), (b), (c), (d) ) != 0 ? abort() : (void)0 )

#define PTH_join( a, b ) \
    (pthread_join( (a), (b) ) != 0 ? abort() : (void)0 )

#define PTH_rwlock_rdlock( a ) \
    (pthread_rwlock_rdlock( (a) ) != 0 ? abort() : (void)0 )

#define PTH_rwlock_wrlock( a ) \
    (pthread_rwlock_wrlock( (a) ) != 0 ? abort() : (void)0 )

#define PTH_rwlock_unlock( a ) \
    (pthread_rwlock_unlock( (a) ) != 0 ? abort() : (void)0 )

static void *firstReader(
    void *arg
);

static void *firstWriter(
    void *arg
);

static void *secondReader(
    void *arg
);

static pthread_rwlock_t rwlock  = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    pthread_t   thr1;
    pthread_t   thr2;
    pthread_t   thr3;

    PTH_create( &thr1, NULL, firstReader, NULL );
    PTH_create( &thr2, NULL, firstWriter, NULL );
    PTH_create( &thr3, NULL, secondReader, NULL );

    PTH_join( thr1, NULL );
    PTH_join( thr2, NULL );
    PTH_join( thr3, NULL );

    return 0;
}

static void *firstReader( void *arg )
{
    printf( "first reader acquiring lock... \n" );
    PTH_rwlock_rdlock( &rwlock );
    printf( "first reader lock acquired \n" );
    sleep( 10 );
    printf( "first reader releasing lock \n" );
    PTH_rwlock_unlock( &rwlock );
    return NULL;
}

static void *firstWriter( void *arg )
{
    sleep( 2 );
    printf( "first writer acquiring lock... \n" );
    PTH_rwlock_wrlock( &rwlock );
    printf( "first writer lock acquired \n" );
    sleep( 10 );
    printf( "first writer releasing lock \n" );
    PTH_rwlock_unlock( &rwlock );
    return NULL;
}

static void *secondReader( void *arg )
{
    sleep( 5 );
    printf( "second reader acquiring lock... \n" );
    PTH_rwlock_rdlock( &rwlock );
    printf( "second reader lock acquired \n" );
    sleep( 5 );
    printf( "second reader releasing lock \n" );
    PTH_rwlock_unlock( &rwlock );
    return NULL;
}
```

Additional info:

From the posix standard: the macro `_POSIX_THREAD_PRIORITY_SCHEDULING` indicates whether the Thread Execution Scheduling option is supported. From `unistd.h`: "If these symbols are defined, the corresponding features are always available..." then lists `_POSIX_THREAD_PRIORITY_SCHEDULING`. Again from posix: "If the Thread Execution Scheduling option is supported, and the threads involved in the lock are executing with the scheduling policies `SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`, the calling thread shall not acquire the lock if a writer holds the lock... ." So I have a program (below) which shows on my Linux system that `_POSIX_THREAD_PRIORITY_SCHEDULING` is defined, BUT I am not able to force the thread policy to `SCHED_RR` (I also tried `SCHED_FIFO`, bt that's not shown in the program).

Additional thoughts? Thanks to all...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define PTH_create( a, b, c, d ) \
    (pthread_create( (a), (b), (c), (d) ) != 0 ? abort() : (void)0 )

#define PTH_join( a, b ) \
    (pthread_join( (a), (b) ) != 0 ? abort() : (void)0 )

static void *driver(
    void *arg
);

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    pthread_attr_t  attr;
    pthread_attr_init( &attr );
    pthread_attr_setschedpolicy( &attr, SCHED_RR );

    pthread_t   thrID;

    PTH_create( &thrID, &attr, driver, NULL );
    printf( "%ld\n", _POSIX_THREAD_PRIORITY_SCHEDULING );
    struct sched_param  param;
    int                 policy;
    pthread_getschedparam( thrID, &policy, &param );
    if ( policy == SCHED_FIFO )
        puts( "SCHED_FIFO" );
    else if ( policy == SCHED_RR )
        puts( "SCHED_RR" );
    else if ( policy == SCHED_FIFO )
        puts( "SCHED_FIFO" );
    else if ( policy == SCHED_OTHER )
        puts( "SCHED_OTHER" );
    else
        puts( "eh?" );

    PTH_join( thrID, NULL );

    return 0;
}

static void *driver( void *arg )
{
    sleep( 2 );
    return NULL;
}

$ ./sched_test
200809
SCHED_OTHER
```

Comment: Did you file a bug for this?

Comment: Not yet... not that I have added additional info to my question.

Comment: You must also set a `sched_priority` using `pthread_attr_setschedparam()`, because `SCHED_RR` and `SCHED_FIFO` require a non-zero `sched_priority`.  You'll also need to make sure that your `RLIMIT_RTPRIO` resource limit (`ulimit -r`) is greater than or equal to the `sched_priority` value that you set.

Answer (score 3):

You missed this sentence in POSIX:

> If the Thread Execution Scheduling option is not supported, it is
>   implementation-defined whether the calling thread acquires the lock
>   when a writer does not hold the lock and there are writers blocked on
>   the lock.

You can't rely on POSIX rwlocks favouring writers over readers.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still having problems; I added additional info to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in the Linux pthreads implementation.  Works correctly on FreeBSD:

```
first reader acquiring lock... 
first reader lock acquired 
first writer acquiring lock... 
second reader acquiring lock... 
first reader releasing lock 
first writer lock acquired 
first writer releasing lock 
second reader lock acquired 
second reader releasing lock
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

- Any number of readers can hold the lock concurrently.
- At most one reader at a time can hold the lock.
- Readers and writers cannot hold the lock concurrently.

Taking your example:

- `first reader acquiring lock...` → OK as no one is holding the lock
- `first reader lock acquired`
- `first writer acquiring lock...` → blocks because a reader is holding the lock
- `second reader acquiring lock...` → OK as only readers are holding the lock
- `second reader lock acquired`
- `first reader releasing lock` → second reader is still holding the lock
- `second reader releasing lock` → no one is holding the lock any more
- `first writer lock acquired`
- `first writer releasing lock`

Also, there is no universal solution: The second reader might release the lock well before the first reader does, in which case the above behvaior would be beneficial. Or the second reader might run for a long time, while the first reader and the writer finish up quickly, in which case it would be beneficial to grant resources strictly in the order in which they were requested.